# Add filter to Middleman "previous article" loop

Tags: ruby-on-rails, erb, middleman

I'm pretty new to this, so I hope I get this right.

I'm building a portfolio site with Middleman. I've activated the blog extension and I use articles as case studies. The articles contain "featured" in their front matter, which I either set to "true" or "false".

The "featured: true" articles are displayed on the homepage. At the bottom of these articles I've added the following code to be able to navigate to the previous and next articles:

```
<% prev_article = current_article.previous_article %>
<% if prev_article %>
  <a href="<%= prev_article.url %>"><%= prev_article.title %></a>
<% end %>
```

Thing is, I would like to add a filter so that just the articles with "featured: true" are added to this loop. The loop needs to skip the non-featured articles.

I've tried the following:

```
<% prev_article = current_article.previous_article %>
<% if prev_article && prev_article.data.featured == "true" %>
  <a href="<%= prev_article.url %>"><%= prev_article.title %></a>
<% end %>
```

But, as expected, this outputs nothing because both conditions aren't met.

To clarify: let's say that articles 1, 3, 5 and 7 are featured and articles 2, 4 and 6 are not featured.

If I'm reading article 3, I need the previous navigation to skip article 2 and go directly to article 1, because that one is featured while 2 isn't.

Hope anyone can help me :)

Answer (score 0):

I think I have it now. Create a helper class in the helpers map for example: article_helper.rb like this

```
class ArticleHelper

  def get_previous

  end
end
```

Then in youre config.rb file add this:

```
helpers do
  def get_previous(article)
    if article.previous_article.present? && article.previous_article.data.featured
      '<a href="' + article.previous_article.url +'">' + article.previous_article.title + '</a>'
    elsif !article.previous_article.present?
      return
    else
      get_previous(article.previous_article)
    end
  end
end
```

restart your server and hopefully if you put this in your view it works

```
<%= get_previous(current_article) %>
```

I hope this does the trick for you

Comment: Thanks, but that just removes the link to the previous article altogether because both conditions aren't met (yes, there is a previous article but no, it isn't featured). I need this loop to skip the non-featured articles and just include the featured ones.

Comment: Thanks again, Robbert, but that doesn't work either. For some reason this helper appears to be ignored - all articles (including the non-featured ones) are still included in the loop.

Comment: Does the helper method not get called when you call it in youre view?

Comment: I think not. Unless I'm doing it incorrectly; I've added your code to my config.rb file. Also tried adding "helper do" and "end" to top and bottom of code. Tried adding "activate :get_previous" and "activate :get_previous(article)" after the helper, but still no luck. Guess I'm missing something... still pretty new to all this :-/

Comment: you need to put the helper method like this in your view <%= get_previous(current_article) %>

Comment: No, unfortunately it didn't work. Thanks for your help, but I'm starting to think that it isn't possible to have a filtered "next and previous" navigation based on frontmatter. Guess I should start looking into custom collections...